# Fastest way to draw a ton of squares?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I have a collection of Square objects in a list called squares. I iterate over the list and draw each square individually, I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this? I don't think GL_QUAD will work because that fills in the square when I just want the outline.

Here's my code

```
    for sq in squares:
            x1, y1 = sq.point
            x2, y2 = x1 + sq.length - 1, y1 + sq.length - 1
            batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', (x1, y1, x1, y2)))
            batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', (x1, y1, x2, y1)))
            batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', (x2, y2, x1, y2)))
            batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', (x2, y2, x2, y1)))

    batch.draw()
```

(x1,y1) would be the bottom left point of the square and (x2,y2) is the top right.

Comment: Is the code you have not fast enough?

Comment: if its not fast enough you probably need another language ... I doubt you can make significant improvements to this (but it is probably more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com )

Comment: not a py-user (have no idea what batch does but I suspect lists which have usually no performance gain ...) but try VBO or VAO that is basically what you need. also what is not fast enough? try to compute number of triangles per second and compare it to your gfx card specification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenGL you can avoid polygon filling by calling:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

To get filled polygons again use:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

This way, you could use quads or 2 triangles. Using this(glPolygonMode) and vertexs arrays should greatly improve performance.